# How the parameters of callback function work in javascript nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, asynccallback

When we call an asynchronous function if we can pass a callback function with parameters. I am unable to understand that do I need to memorize the order of the parameter in the call back function. 
e.g in express

```
app.get('/',function(req,res))
```

How to know the number of the parameters and the what they contain because I watched a tutorial and I know first req and then res.

Comment: It should be in the API documentation for the library you're using. If not, check the source code.

Comment: `I watched a tutorial and I know first req and then res` for that particular function ... but, in general, the API's in node that use callbacks, the callback usually takes `(err, result)` - if err is not falsey - it contains an error, otherwise `result` contains a result of some kind - you'll find this pattern very common in nodejs

Comment: How do these parameters work meaning first it get the '/' link at the port then it call the function .How are the value to these function are given ? Where do node pass the value to req and res

Answer (score 1):

> When we call an asynchronous function if we can pass a callback function with parameters.

Depends on the function. Modern ones tend to return a Promise instead of accepting a callback.

> do I need to memorize the order of the parameter in the call back function.

No, you can look them up.

> How to know the number of the parameters and the what they contain

By reading the documentation for the function you are passing the callback to

Comment: Quentin @Quentin #Quentin So I need to look up for the documentation to see the parameters to use and cannot we call a functikn without call back function

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this code. You can see there are 2 middleware functions before we get inside the get method(Passed like array of functions). Another middleware after the get method. This will give you a rudimentary understanding of the sequential way request gets handled and how request can be manipulated.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



var middleware1 = function(req,res,next){
  console.log("Before Get method middleware")
  console.log("middleware1");
  next();
}
var middleware2 = function(req,res,next){
  console.log("middleware2");
  next();
}

app.get("/", [middleware1 , middleware2],(req, res, next) => {
    console.log("inside Get middleware")
    req['newparam'] = "somevalue"; // or somecode modiffication to request object
    next(); //calls the next middleware
});

app.use('/',function(req,res){
  console.log("After Get method middleware")
  console.log(req['newparam']); //the added new param can be seen
  res.send("Home page");
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Comment: Hello, Mr. Sairohith. The code snippet you posted was very helpful. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

app.get or any app.[CRUD Method] takes 2 or 3 params (**request**, **response**, **next**) in the same order. The **next** is **optional**

Comment: Where can I find the source code of the function get? I went to the GitHub and cannot find the get function. Plz, send me the documentation link because in nodejs.com it is hard for me to read the link

Comment: I read the documetation somewhat it was just telling that in app.get (path,callback,[callback]) and said you can pass middleware their or array of middleware. I want to get started with node and  I liked it but this topic is confusing me

Comment: That's not a CRUD (create, read, update, delete) method though, it's an HTTP method (get, post, delete, ...).